# app doesn't work with otree 1.4.4

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, otree

I have an otree app that works perfectly on my computer, with otree 1.3.1.

In this app, I specify several settings variables. One of those is called "sure", which can take values 0 or 1, and I refer to it in models.py and views.py as self.settings.config['sure']. In my html page, I have several conditions as "{% if sure == 1 %}" or {% if sure == 0 %}.

When trying to run it on the computer of the lab (which has the new version of otree, 1.4.4 ), I have the following problem:

The file models.py reads it fine, so when I ask to print "sure" on the terminal, it prints the right value of the variable.

The file views.py cannot read it, so in the html page it makes a mess: some things it shows as if "sure" == 0, others as if "sure" == 1, and when I ask to show it in the html page, using {{sure}}, it shows nothing. It doesn't show any error messages. The problem is only with the settings variable "sure", and only with the version 1.4.4 of otree.

By now, the only solution I can think of is to re-write the app without the "sure" variable, so to make one version for "sure" == 0, and one version for "sure" == 1, but I would like to avoid it.

Did anyone had a similar problem and knows how to fix it ? Or anyone might guess what is causing the problem? Can it be a bug of otree?

Thank you so much,

Chiara

EDIT : I solved the problem, which was very stupid at the end: in the new version of otree the views.py file should be called pages.py ! I don't know if I should delete the question or if it might be useful for somebody.!